# More efficient HashMap (Dictionary) for Python for use in big data

Tags: python, string, dictionary, bigdata

I'm creating a program that counts the occurrences of strings in a huge file. For this I have used the python dictionary with the strings as keys and the counts as the values.

The program works fine for smaller files of up to 10000 strings. But when I test it out on my actual file **~ 2-3 mil** strings, my program starts to slow down when it reaches the 50% mark to about 50% of it's original speed.

I suspect this is because the built in dictionary was not meant to handle such large volumes of data and is getting a lot more collisions. I would like to know if there is any efficient way of solving this problem. I was looking for alternative hashmap implementations or even making a list of hashmaps (it slowed it down further).

**Details:**

- The strings are not known beforehand.
- The strings' lengths range is about 10 - 200.
- There are many strings that only occur once (and will be discarded at the end)
- I have already implemented concurrency to speed it up.
- It takes about 1 hour to complete one file

  - I do other calculations too, while that takes up time, it does not slow down on smaller filesizes. So I suspect it's a hashmap or memory issue.
- I have plenty of memory, when running it only takes up 8GB of 32GB.

Comment: As you noticed, making a more complex data structure is not necessarily going to make things faster. Python's dictionary is carefully designed and well-tuned; you'll be hard pressed to do better than it in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I suspect this is because the built in dictionary was not meant to handle such large volumes of data and is getting a lot more collisions.

**High collision rates are not the likely cause.**  Python dictionaries resize as they grow so they don't get more than two-thirds full.  This keeps collisions down to a reasonable rate regardless of size.

**The likely cause is that the data has grown larger than the L3 cache** (commonly about 6Mb).  Beyond that, regular DRAM accesses will be about twice as slow (see the memory latency graph from ExtremeTech below).

Given that this is a hardware issue, **an alternate dictionary implementation won't  help**.

---

[image: https://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/latency.png]

Comment: In this case, is there anything I can do, short of buying a new CPU with more cache? I was thinking of splitting the files into smaller files and then process them individually. Eventually having one final pass to merge all the hashes.

Comment: @CJX3711 One extreme measure is to edit CPython's dictionary object to assume that a hash match implies equality.  That would save the expensive string comparisons for duplicates.  The edit is in Objects/dictobject.c lookdict() and its kin with something like ``if (ep->me_hash == hash) { return ix; }``.    This isn't perfect but the chance of a false positive is 1 in 2**64.

Comment: How about a pre-pass to split the file by a relevant criterion, like by string length or by the string's first character?  Pick "the right" criteria (which I can't guess without seeing the data's distribution), and the resulting chunks will be much smaller, and strings from different chunks can't be equal.

Comment: I did more testing and it turns out that it was indeed nothing to do the python hash. I was also using python difflib and I suspect that it was the cause of the slowdown after processing large amounts of data. Probably due to some caching thing? I'm not entirely sure. I ended up figuring out how to reduce the initial dataset in a step prior to this so this slowdown no longer became a problem.